# Add static text before or after a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm new to Android Dev and I try to figure a gently way to add static text before and after a dynamic part in a TextView, without having to add 2 other TextView or add these content each time I update the dynamic part of my TextView.

Something just like ::after or ::before with content propertie in CSS.

Something which could look like this :

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="10"
  android:textAfter=" km/h" />
```

I digged Google up and down (went to 3rd page sometimes) but I couldn't find any way to do this trick which appear pretty basic to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you just need a custom TextView. Then you can make one.

**First**, declare custom attributes for your CustomTextView. Create a new file named `attrs.xml` in `/res/values`. fill it with code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="textAfter" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**Second**, Create Your CustomTextView as a java file. That's simple. You just need get the value of attribute of `textAfter` and set it to the tail of the text when `setText` is invoked.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    private String mTextAfter;

    public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
        mTextAfter = array.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_textAfter);
        array.recycle();
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text + (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTextAfter) ? "" : mTextAfter), type);
    }
}
```

**Thrid**, use the `CustomTextView` in layout.(Do NOT forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in the root view of your layout)

```
<!-- your package name -->
<com.xxx.xxx.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/mtv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:textAfter=" km/h" />
```

**Fourth**, use it in `XXXActivity.java`.

```
    //TextView mtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtv));// this is worked too
    CustomTextView mtv = ((CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.mtv));
    mtv.setText("18");//do NOT put int value of 18 in it, or it will be treated as a resource id
```

Then you will see, the `km/h` is added after `18`.

[image: CustomTextView]

Answer (score 3):

You can use string resource for dynamic text with a predefined format using `%d` or `%1$d`.

For example, if you want to show something like `10 km/h`, you can use string resource like this:

```
<string name="range_in_kilometer_per_hour">%d km/h</string>
```

Then you can set it via code with:

```
TextView tvKm;
...
int currentKm = 10;
String kmValue = getString(R.string.range_in_kilometer_per_hour, currentKm);

tvKm.setText(kmValue);
```

Or if you want to show something like `10 km each 1 hour`, you can use something like:

```
<string name="range_in_kilometer_per_hour">%1$d km each %2$d hour</string>
```

Then set it to your TextView with:

```
int currentKm = 10;
int hour = 1;
String kmValue = getString(R.string.range_in_kilometer_per_hour, currentKm, hour);

tvKm.setText(kmValue);
```

If you want to use string instead of an integer, you can use `%s` for single text replacement, or `%1$s` for multiple text replacement.

You need to remember that the means of **1** in `%1$s` is the position of the text replacement.

Read more at:

1. [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)
2. [getString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...))

Comment: Your answer is nice but I prefer Relish Wang's one because it avoid to create a String ressource for each TextView

Comment: It should work, but it's losing the flexibility to support multiple language in internationalization

Comment: Yep you're right but in my case this app is an intern tool

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this
remove text in xml i.e. km/hr
go to your activity java file let it be activity_main.java
Dynamically get the value of speed
say for
`int speed;`
then in textview(xml)
assign any id `android:id="@+id/speedTextView"`

in java
assign speed value
`TextView speedWithUnit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedTextView);`
and
`speedWithUnit.setText(speed+"km/hr");`

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks but like I said I try to figure a way to avoid to add "km/h" each time I update speed

Comment: Untill then you may set visibility of TextView to GONE and then back to VISIBLE